# When was Alex Kingston told this?

Tags: doctor-who

Alex Kingston’s character River Song is

> Amy Ponds daughter,

but when was Alex Kingston told this information so she could incorporate it into her acting scenes with Amy prior to Amy finding out and was she told prior to Karen Gilian finding out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alex Kingston was told of her relationship to Amy and Rory just before the filming of season six but she didn't realise she was Melody Pond until she read the actual episode script. Karen Gillan only found out along with the rest of the cast the other cast upon reading of the mid-season cliffhanger script for "A Good Man Goes To War"

> Q: What was your reaction when you found out you were actually Melody
> Pond? Where you surprised?
>
> AK: I was surprised. Yes, yes, I was not expecting that at all.
>
> AK: Steven hadn't warned me. He told me that I was their child but he
> didn't tell me that I was Melody Pond

Source:

question @ 3.10 minutes.

> The character was originally created purely for the plot of "Silence
> in the Library".
>
> When Kingston returned to the show, Moffat explained to her some
> details about her back-story, knowledge which Smith, Gillan and
> Darvill did not receve until later.
>
> For the filming of the sixth series, Kingston was aware of River
> Song's relationship to Amy and Rory while the other cast only found
> out upon reading of the mid-season cliffhanger script for "A Good Man
> Goes To War".

Source: Doctor Who Guide ISBN 978-1-291-07980-7

Comment: The OP had a spoiler to this, so maybe adding one in the answer too, would be nice?

Comment: First air date of " A Good Man Goes to War" was 4 June 2011. It's now July 2020. What's the statute of limitations on spoilers?

Comment: No clue, I suggested it just to be consistent with how the question was asked.

Comment: Some people still put "Luke, I am your father" on spoiler blocks...although it's maybe a joke...

Comment: Some people are just now starting to watch the series. They may come here for explanations and wonder across interesting questions for episodes they haven't yet watched. Of course, that's the risk one takes...